# Add custom page editor buttons to a FieldRenderer's edit frame

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore6, page-editor

If I have a `<sc:FieldRenderer>` or related control in a sublayout, and I wrap it in a `<sc:Link>` control, the `FieldRenderer` will have an additional button to edit the link field, rather than a second wrapping `EditFrame`.

Is it possible for other buttons to be added to the built-in field renderer controls in the same manner rather than using an `<sc:EditFrame>` control?

For example, if I used the following markup:

<sub>Good:</sub>

```
<div class="example">
    <sc:Text runat="server" ID="Text" Field="Text" />
</div>
```

Is it possible to add custom buttons to the edit frame shown in the page editor for the `Text` control, *without* needing to rely on an `EditFrame` control?

<sub>Bad:</sub>

```
<div class="example">
    <sc:EditFrame runat="server" ID="Edit">
        <sc:Text runat="server" ID="Text" Field="Text" />
    </sc:EditFrame>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is possible. First, find the field item itself in the CMS. For example you're field is called `Text`, so pretend your field definition item is located at `/sitecore/templates/user defined/My Sample Template/Sample Section/Text`. On that field definition item scroll down to the `Page Editor Buttons` field and you can add any WebEdit buttons to show in the Page Editor selection of that field. Now at this point you may actually need to define a custom WebEdit button.

Comment: As an addition to this, if you only need the extra buttons on specific textfields (but not all), you can use the Rules Engine as described here: http://trayek.wordpress.com/2013/05/15/rules-in-the-page-editor/

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible for other buttons to be added to the built-in field renderer controls in the same manner rather than using an  control?

No. sc:FieldRenderer is a readonly control which serves any text based on its Field name.. its not possible to add additional controls to it. I usually use a .net Literal & keep adding plain HTML coming from sitecore dynamically from code behind

Comment: I'm not asking about adding more content *within* the field renderer. I'm asking about adding an additional page editor button to the field renderer.